# How compatible are different Android versions?

Tags: android

So, I'm current trying to learn and become a programmer. I've recently worked with C# but I really want to get into mobile apps, since most small projects really tend to fit better as mobile apps, rather than desktop apps.

The easiest, for me, seems to be the Android platform, but I'm having a problem... I don't own an android phone, but I could possibly purchase an old model. Naturally these will have an older version of Android, so here is my question...

How compatible are these different versions? Like, are there major differences when moving from Icecream Sandwich to Jelly Bean, or from KitKat to Lollipop?

How do app developers deal with this array of Android versions?

Comment: when you start a project in Android studio and you select a Target SDK  lets say 23 which is Android Marshmallow it tells you the percentage of the compatible devices on the market

Comment: Older ones are pretty different. Animations became much more powerful in Ice Cream Sandwich for instance. A great way to check version usage is in this link http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/dashboards/index.html, generally supporting Jelly Bean and above works best as you don't need to handle poor hardware.

Comment: Have a look at [compatibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html)

Comment: Thank you, I actually found that link before and it was that page that got me worried about this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you develop an app for an old version of Android, it will run without errors on all newer version of Android, unless you do something involving low-level stuff like direct kernel calls, but you will never encounter such issues if you only use Java.

Worst issue you'll see is your app visual style looking outdated on newer devices.

If you target API level 23 / Android 6.0 Marshmallow, you will still need to run your app on Android 6.0 emulator, to be sure that it won't crash when using new Android permission dialogs to ask for SD card access etc.

Comment: Thank you, this was very much what I was hoping to hear. So I can start out with an old phone and those apps should run without errors on a newer device, with a newer version of Android.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Android apps can use newest API while still allowing to run on old devices, and Android Studio by default targets newest API level available, it's explained in detail here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Comment: Ahh, so they can also be backward compatible. A very helpful link. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I currently have an old Samsung Galaxy Trend. It has Icecream Sandwich at the moment, so I'll see if I can update it to Jelly Bean and I'll start with that.